# Problemas para subir Proyecto Laravel 8 a un subdominio en Hostinger

Tags: servidor, laravel-8, hosting

estoy tratando de subir mi proyecto Laravel 8 a un subdominio en Hostinger pero me esta dando batalla, esta es la estructura de mis carpetas ya cargadas en el hostinger, me estoy basando en un articulo del propio hostinger para subir el proyecto https://support.hostinger.es/es/articles/6273595-como-implementar-laravel-8-en-hostinger pero no se si el problema se deba a que yo tengo hosting compartido entonces lo tengo que subir a un subdominio y este articulo es para dominios

Solución:

- Actualizar versión de php en Hostinger
- Crear el subdominio apuntando a la carpeta **public**:

  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

  Seleccionar "**carpeta personalizada**", luego poner el nombre del subdominio, por ejemplo test123@tudominio.com y en donde dice "Directorio", poner test123/public ya que el hosting intentara cargar tu proyecto desde la raiz y en el caso de laravel la raiz es el index.php de public:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con esto te quedara algo asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Borrar esas carpetas **public** y **default.php**

- Todavía en forma local, limpiar el cache de tu proyecto con los
  siguientes comandos en consola:
- php artisan cache:clear

  php artisan view:clear

  php artisan config:clear

  php artisan event:clear

  php artisan route:clear
- Luego comprimir proyecto en formato .zip
- Subir archivo .zip a hostinger en carpeta test123 y descomprimir, al
  descomprimir te pedirá que crees una carpeta para los archivos, ponle
  cualquier nombre a la carpeta ejemplo **descomprimir**, despues mueves
  todos los archivos de la carpeta descomprimir a la carpeta test123

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

- Crear base de datos en hostinger, después migrar base de datos sea por ssh o manualmente
- Modificar archivo .env configurando la conexión a la base de datos e indicar la APP_URL (es la url de tu subdominio en este caso test123@tudominio.com)

Y listo, debe quedar funcionando tu proyecto, en mi caso elimine las carpetas de node.js por que no las ocupaba y hacian que mi proyecto no cargara los estilos y js, en caso de ese error mi recomendación es eliminar la carpeta y el webpack

Comment: el local te funciona asi? que error es el que muestra?

Comment: No, asi es como los tengo en Hostinger, me muestra el error 500 pero no me da mas detalles

Comment: y no as probado el local, como sabes que todo esta bien?

Comment: Si, en local me funciona bien, me guie por el articulo de hostinger https://support.hostinger.es/es/articles/6273595-como-implementar-laravel-8-en-hostinger, pero yo utilizo un subdominio y al parecer esa documentación que segui es para  dominios.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución ya quedó registrada arriba, gracias.